# Common method for activity and fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a layout section which is part of a Fragment and its a layout for the activity.

fragment.xml

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:scrollbars="none”> 
      <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
            <include layout="@layout/sectional_component"/>
            <include layout="@layout/list_component" />
            <include layout="@layout/usage_component" />
      </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

list_component.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list"
    style="@style/VerticalMatchParent">

    // programatically added top 3 customer list

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/list"
style="@style/VerticalMatchParent">

    // programmatically render all customer list

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm new to android. I wanted to use a common method for rendering the list based on the request (3 or all). For now, I have written a separate method in Fragment and in an activity to handle this.
I want to make it as a single method which can be used by the fragment as well as an activity since the functionality is nearly same. I tried to make it as a separate util method, but the issue I'm facing is inside the method I have do manipulations for the view elements not sure how to do it without inflating the view element layouts. Already the layouts having the view elements are inflated in the respective Fragment and Activity.

Kindly provide a solution for this.

Comment: can you please share that method of yours

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to do this, one of them would be to create an static method inside a separated class, pass the required parameters and call it wherever you want.

Class `MyClass`:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static View myMethod(View myView){
        // Do whatever you want with your View
        return myView;
    }
}
```

Call to `myMethod` from `MyClass`:

```
View modifiedView = MyClass.myMethod(myView);
```

If you need to handle some Views send them to the method as a list, array or whatever

Comment: Thanks for your response, I wish to send the entire activity view to that method. how to send it? from the Fragment, I will send the inflated view object

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that, why do you want to send the whole Activity Tree View? You usually modify the data to add to the Views not the Views itself.

Comment: Thanks will try it

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on populating a list, you can go for `listView`. And write an `adapter` class to populate your list on it.

- **Note:** You need a separate layout file with design for listView saved under you `layout` folder.

Hope this helps!